# How to set a level of confidence for watson conversation?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-dialog

I would like to understand how to create a way to redirect the conversation to the `anything_else` node when `confidence` is lower then a established limit.

I am creating a node triggered by `intents[0].confidence < 0.5` that jumps to the `anything_else` answer.

So if I enter a value "huaiuhsuskunwku" it recognizes as the intent `#greetings` and do redirect its node.

Any idea why it is recognizing it as a greeting in the first place?

And how can I configure it properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two things here:
 1a. Before the newest API was released, which is still beta, we used what is called a relational classifier. Meaning it checks all the classes available, and will do its best to fit it into the most similar one. So I would assume you have relatively few intents, and each intent has only a handful of samples. There are too many features in the algorithm to point to one specifically, but its finding some features that make it think it is part of that class. 
 1b. You should create a class for off-topic that just includes a bunch of things you dont want to respond to. This essentially helps balance out the existing classes so it knows it is NOT your main classes. You wont need any dialog nodes for this, the off-topic class simply helps it fall to anything else as you want
 2. Just this week we have released an update to the API. This changes it to an absolute classifier so scoring is handled differently now. Each class is evaluated on its own. We have also included a built in off-topic handler to help weed out gibberish like this. See the docs here:
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/release-notes.html

Answer (score 0):

Watson follows Top to Bottom Flow. So there may be 2 cases.

1. Your Greeting node is above to the one which you created for routing to Anything else and that your query's (huaiuhsuskunwku) confidence was >=0.20 for #greeting intent. In this case just move your greetings dialog below to the node you created.
2. If your greeting dialog is below to the node you created for routing to Anything else dialog. The given condition(confidence < 0.5) failed and thus skipped that dialog. In this case, check the confidence of that query in 'Try it' window and adjust confidence value in dialog accordingly.