# Percent chance of coincidence

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Good afternoon

The wizard is entering the intentions with less than 0.3 percent chance of coincidence, I need a minimum of 0.7 percent or the intent of anything_else.
Where can I configure that?

Greetings

Comment: Do you mean confidence?

Comment: You may wish to read the following; How To Set the Optimal Confidence Threshold for Your Assistant [https://medium.com/ibm-watson/how-to-set-the-optimal-confidence-threshold-for-your-assistant-bbb1be6f294f]  or How to set a level of confidence for watson conversation? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095691/how-to-set-a-level-of-confidence-for-watson-conversation ]

Comment: Sorry, the link is broken

Yes, confidence. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can check intents or anything else using the expression I have provided below.  At "intentName" you can replace with the intent you are checking.

```
anything_else || (intents.size() > 0 && intents[0] == 'intentName' && intents[0].confidence > 0.7)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement what you recommended, but now it almost always goes into this node, no matter I put it at 0.3 percent confidence :(